# How to un-cache a dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, databricks

I'm seeing strange behavior in Pyspark (Databricks) where a SQL query in a new notebook returns results, however when I apply `LIMIT 100` to the SQL, or `limit(100)` to the dataframe, I get no results (whereas I expect to see the first 100).

In a **separate** notebook that operates with the same `SELECT * FROM VIEW_XYZ` I apply `limit(100)` and then cache() the dataframe. This may be a factor? Totall separate notebooks, but same SQL query.

I have a hypothesis that `cache()` has overzealously cached the query `SELECT * FROM VIEW_XYZ LIMIT 100` along with its results from almost two weeks ago. That's about how long this query has been returning "nothing" as my notebook runs hourly.

To test this hypothesis, I would like to "un-cache" the query/dataframe. How do I un-cache it?

EDIT: Adding the database name to the view `dbname.viewname` fixed it. I don't know why or how.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think `cache` has anything to do with your problem.

To uncache everything you can use `spark.catalog.clearCache()`. Or try **restarting** the cluster, `cache` persists data over the cluster, so if it restarts `cache` will be empty, and you can verify that its not a `cache` related issue.

All your notebooks might be attached to the same cluster which might be giving random errors because of some **old version of runtime**.

Try **creating new cluster with latest runtime**, old clusters with old runtime do act weird sometimes. Sometimes **notebooks that have too much output and too many commands** act like this. Just start using the new one and you might never see any such problem.

A general advice is to **use LTS version of runtime**.
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.databricks.com/runtime/dbr.html).